# Angular-translate using in controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular-translate for i18n in an AngularJS application.

**Code:**

```
angular
    .module('Test')
    .controller('AlertsCtrl', ['$translate', '$scope', AlertsCtrl]);

function AlertsCtrl($translate, $scope) {
    // Api: http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service
    $translate('ALERT_MSG_1', 'ALERT_MSG_2').then(function (line) {
        $scope.alerts = [{
            type: 'success',
            msg: line['ALERT_MSG_1'] // Dosn't work
        }, {
            type: 'danger',
            msg: line['ALERT_MSG_2'] // Dosn't work
        }];
        console.log("In");
    });

    console.log("--- " + $translate.instant('ALERT_MSG_2')); // Works

    $scope.addAlert = function () {
        $scope.alerts.push({
            msg: 'Another alert!'
        });
    };

    $scope.closeAlert = function (index) {
        $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };
}
```

**Problem:**

The *line['ALERT_MSG_1']* and the *line['ALERT_MSG_2']* dosnt give back anything. Why?

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

you should use array it you want to translate multiple strings. i.e.

```
$translate(['ALERT_MSG_1', 'ALERT_MSG_2']).then(function (line) {
    $scope.alerts = [{
        type: 'success',
        msg: line['ALERT_MSG_1'] // Dosn't work
    }, {
        type: 'danger',
        msg: line['ALERT_MSG_2'] // Dosn't work
    }];
    console.log("In");
});
```